# Querying BigQuery Events data in PowerBI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, data-connections

Hi I have analytics events data moved from firebase to BigQuery and need to create visualization in PowerBI using that BigQuery dataset. I'm able to access the dataset in PowerBI but some fields are in array type I generally use UNNEST while querying in console but how to run the query inside PowerBI. Is there any other option available? Thanks.
[image: In PowerBI]
Table In BigQuery
[image]

Comment: could you show your table, mostly in PowerBI it is easily expandable.

Comment: I have added the image . Thanks @AnkUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did until the driver fully supports arrays is to flatten in a view: create a view in bigquery with `UNNEST()` and query that in PBI instead.

Comment: Thanks Yannick but can we create dynamic view on BigQuery?

Answer (score -1):

You might need to Transform(parse Json into columns/rows) your specific column in your case `event_params`

So I have below Json as example for you.

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had this json added to my table. currently it has only 1 column
[image]

Now I go to Edit queries and go on Transform Tab, there you find Parse, In my case I have Json

[image]

When you parse as Json you will have expandable column
[image]

Now click on expanding it and sometimes it asks for expand to new row.
[image]

Finally you will have such a Table
[image]

Comment: BigQuery ODBC driver does not pass schema  details for ARRAY of RECORD. Also a JSON transform is slow in PBI

Comment: just a question, does it mean we cannot transform array of records into columns/rows just like we transform Json?

Comment: That's correct because the JSON returned by the Simba drivers (ODBC/JDBC) do not include the actual field names, only dummy `v` or `f`